# Openstack on top of google compute engine... does it make sense?

Tags: openstack, google-compute-engine

Im building a SaaS application that exposes users websites to the internet, thus causing me to need a flexible underlayer with computing power that varies...    in order to achieve this, I figured that openstack may make my life easier by allowing me to adjust the computing nodes under my application without interfering with the application itself.

If i didnt use openstack, i figure the application would have to somehow attach and detach nodes...  and that seems like a mess with load balancing and mirrored databases and memcache and stuff..

Also...  im curious if google compute engine will work well with openstack....   do they expose intel-vt or amd-v?    Is there another cloud that does expose this stuff?

Comment: OpenStack is something with which you create your own cloud.

Comment: Nested virtualization is not supported on GCE.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that companies like [Ravello System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJ5K5q_EXZA) and [Cloudscaling](https://techcrunch.com/2012/10/12/cloudscaling-opens-google-compute-engine-apis-to-openstack-provides-alternative-to-amazon-web-services/) has managed to overcome the nested virtualization issue. In the case of Ravello they have created their own hypervisor HVX.